# Need help to create a loop script to delete previous records from multiple tables using SQL

Tags: sql-server

I got a task that i need to delete records from the ff tables below based on create dates.

Table Name: TableA
Description: delete records that were created 7 days earlier.

Table Name: TableB
Description: delete records that were created 7 days earlier.

Table Name: TableC
Description: delete records that were created 6 days earlier.

Table Name: TableD
Description: delete records that were created 6 days earlier.

Table Name: TableE
Description: delete records that were created 6 days earlier.

Table Name: TableF
Description: delete records that were created 6 days earlier.

Here is the code that i created

```
BEGIN TRY  
  
DELETE FROM TableA
 WHERE Createdttm < DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE())    
  
DELETE FROM TableB
 WHERE Createdttm < DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE())   
  
DELETE FROM TableC
 WHERE Createdttm < DATEADD(MONTH,-6,GETDATE())   
  
DELETE FROM TableD
 WHERE Createdttm < DATEADD(MONTH,-6,GETDATE())   
  
DELETE FROM TableE  
 WHERE Createdttm < DATEADD(MONTH,-6,GETDATE())   
  
DELETE FROM TableF 
 WHERE Createdttm < DATEADD(MONTH,-6,GETDATE())   
  
END TRY
```

Can anyone help me create a loop script on this one? I will really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Mysql does not have try,getdate or dateadd so I have changed the tag to sqlserver.

Comment: Have a look at the second answer in the duplicate question, if you want to do it all in the database.

Comment: Sorry for closing as duplicate. The tag was changed afterwards. I'm voting to reopen the question.

Comment: @fancyPants how can i reopen again this question? Im sorry im a newbie here in stackoverflow.

Comment: You can't do anything in this case. I already voted to reopen. The question is now in a review queue. One or two others will also have a look at it and reopen the question. Please have a little bit more patience. And again, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: No worries. Thanks @fancyPants.

Comment: Any other way would result in using dynamic SQL, and IMO the standard way is better.

Comment: No idea what a "loop script" is nor what your actual goal is. Clarify that and the question might be reopened. But it should remain closed without more details.

Comment: Why do you want to loop? Your code says/does exactly what is needed. You could avoid repetition by using variables instead of repeating `dateadd()` expressions, but loops don't seem able to help.